# How do we give proper attribution when using image assets in an application?

Tags: united-states, licensing

How do we give proper attribution when using image assets in an application? I am using a logo image asset on a dashboard application and I was wondering what legally is considered to be proper attribution. I put a comment inside the code where I added the logo linking to where I got the image, but the issue is that this comment is not visible to the people using the application. Is this still ok?

Answer (score 2):

### Attribution is not (necessarily) a legal requirement

If the image is public domain or your usage is fair use/fair dealing under copyright law, attribution is not legally required. However, it is polite.

If you are using it under license, then the license will specify attribution requirements.

Comment: [The most common image attribution license (CC BY) gives best practices guidelines](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution), but do not touch on the problem of when images can be used detached from the text that accompanies them, as when embedded in an interactive application.  It seems to me a difficult problem, especially when tied to "NoDerivatives" so one cannot embed attribution in the image.